# difference between com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment and android.support.v4.app.fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

i am working on Google map implementation in android ,but i am confuse in between com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment and android.support.v4.app.fragment so please deffrentiate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`com.google.android.gms.maps.mapfragment`(For **API Level 11 & above**) ***OR*** `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`(For **API Level below 11** use *android-support-v4.jar*) :

It is a **specialized Fragment used to display a Map component** in an app. which comes with the **google-play-services.jar**. This fragment is the simplest way to place a map in an application. It's a **wrapper around a view of a map to automatically handle the necessary life cycle needs**. Being a fragment, this component can be added to an activity's layout file simply with the XML below.

```
/**** use SupportMapFragment instead of MapFragment for API Level below 11 ****/
<fragment
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

---

`android.app.fragment`(For **API Level 11 & above**) ***OR*** `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`(For **API Level below 11** use *android-support-v4.jar*):

A Fragment represents a **behavior or a portion of user interface in an Activity**; which **comes with the default SDK (or support-library-v4.jar)**. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. It is **not specially made for Maps** & so it **does not support any gestures** which a MapFragment has by default. ***One need to customize the Fragment class to add any gestures or touch events***. We can add a Fragment to an activity's layout file simply with the XML below.

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.MyFragment"
android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment` is a specialized `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`. It displays map. Simple fragment is doing nothing.